# MySQL order by two column, one ASC and one RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to order a table by two columns: `prioritet` and `id`

I want to order `prioritet` with `ASC` and `id` with `RAND()`

The query I've got so far is:

```
 SELECT id, user_id, active, prioritet 
 FROM `agents` 
 WHERE user_id = ' + user_id + ' AND active = \'1\' 
 ORDER BY prioritet ASC, id ASC, RAND()
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Please, post table's structure, sample of data and desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your `order by`:

```
ORDER BY prioritet ASC, id ASC, RAND()
```

It is ordering by `prioiritet` and then by `id`.  You want:

```
ORDER BY prioritet ASC, RAND()
```

In other words, don't order by `id` at all.

This assumes that `id` is unique on each row (which is reasonable given the name).  If ids are not unique, you need a more complex query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.active, a.prioritet
FROM agents a join
     (select id, rand() as r
      from (select distinct id from agents) a
     ) randid
     on a.id = randid.id
WHERE user_id = ' + user_id + ' AND active = \'1\'
ORDER BY a.prioritet ASC, randid.r, a.id;
```

That is, you need to assign a random value to each id, join it back in, and order appropriately.  You only need this if the assumption that `id` is unique is not true.

Comment: Even if this is correct, why would we ordering by a field and then randomly? It is pointless and for sure it is not good for our server resources.. Am I right?

Comment: @MateiMihai . . . Ordering by `rand()` shouldn't perform much worse than ordering in general (which is expensive).  The field `prioritet` contains a priority (a guess based on the name).  The OP presumably wants all things with the same priority but in explicitly random order.  This seems reasonable for some purposes.